# Remove array elements issue in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a very strange issue in iOS.I have two classes **AViewController** & **BViewController**.
In AViewController i am having an array like

```
@property NsmutableArray *array_one;
```

I am passing some data from one view controller to another in **prepareforsegue** method.

```
 if([self.array_one count]>0)
        {

            viewBController.array_two=self.array_one;

        }
```

then from **BviewController** i am passing back the data like this

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{


    int j;


    [self.delegate setData:self.array_two];

}
```

Then i am in this method doing this work

```
- (void)setData:(NSMutableArray *)data
{
    NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(long)[data count]];
   [self.array_one removeAllObjects];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<[string intValue];i++)
    {
        User *u=[data objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.array_one addObject:u];
    }



}
```

Now what happened is if go to view one controller to another 2 times in second time if i add this line `[self.array_one removeAllObjects];` then my `data` array get empty.I don't know why?
Please guide me

Comment: Sweet combo of `NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(long)[data count]];` and `[string intValue]`.  Well done.

Comment: You only have one actual array, right?  You have two pointers to it (array_one, array_two) but whether you remove objects using one name or another, it's still removing them from a single array.

Comment: @Droppy Sarcasm is wasted on SO.

Comment: In case you missed Droppy's point, in your `setData:` method, get rid of the `string` variable. Change your `for` loop to `for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < data.count; i++)`. Better yet, replace the whole loop with just `[self.array_one addObjectsFromArray:data];`.

Comment: some body suggest me to use string var like that

Comment: Never take advice from that person again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use two different methods of passing the data.

`viewBController.array_two=self.array_one;`

This assigns the `array_two` pointer to be the same as `array_one`. This means that they both point to the same array.

Then, when you call `[self.delegate setData:self.array_two]`, the first thing that happens is that you call `[self.array_one removeAllObjects]`. But this is pointing to the same array as `array_two`, so you will empty the array.

If the data is manifestly the same at all times between the two classes, one solution would just be to assign the array to both view controllers once, after which changes in one will be reflected in the other.

If not, then you need to copy the array to a new object when you assign to the second view controller.

Comment: I guess you are right but the array **data** it just an argument so this should not get empty.I am passing self.array_two in stead as an argument

Comment: You are not passing the whole array, you are passing a pointer to the array. If you don't understand what that means, I suggest looking at some tutorials.

Comment: suggest me some please

Comment: First google result: http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/pointers-in-objective-c/225700236

Comment: I think issue is when i write **viewBController.array_two=self.array_one;** then array is not getting copied their pointer is copied and when use **[self.delegate setData:self.array_two]** then the pointer is passed as an argument which points to one array & when i do **[self.array_one removeAllObjects].** then it empty the array so all three of them were pointing to same array that is why it made an array empty.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the issue.

Comment: so can i remove this?Should i make a loop to add elements of array_one to array_two instead of **viewBController.array_two=self.array_one; ** or what is the way out?

Comment: As I state above, it depends upon what the data is. You might want them to be the same, or you might want to copy just the array, or you might want to deep copy the array and all the containing objects. But you should ask another question if you are still confused, as these comments are not the place for long discussions.

Comment: Data of array_one & array_two will be diffrent always